# A non-inductive behavior in low frequency of an inductor

Tags: impedance, phase

I have a question that has been torturing me for a while now.

I cannot give you guys all the information, however, what I can say is that I have this measurement of an impedance of an electrical machine (winding on a magnetic material.) What I don't get is the values the phase has before the resonance (below 90°). Any idea of what could cause it?

[image]

Sorry for the amount of information I gave, that is really the most I can say.

PS: The magnetic material is not laminated

Comment: Can you show a simplified schematic of your measurement setup without revealing too much?

Comment: @winny it is the inductor connected to an impedance analyzer. I have measured the impedance of windings with no magnetic material, it all seemed physically understandable to me, but this one right here I cannot seem to understand.

Comment: It is not purely reactive because of the power gone out of the system due to eddy currents and magnetic hysteresis.

Comment: @Ayhan Oh I forgot to mention that the magnetic material is not laminated.

Comment: As there are some peaks, the model of inductor should be made of "sections".

Comment: @Antonio51 you mean each turn has it own model? (to reproduce the reflexion phenomena), right?

Comment: Not each turn ... but perhaps some turns together. Don't know how the inductor is wired ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Ok, got you. And what about the iron losses induced in the massive magnetic core?

Comment: I also use a coupling different from 1, because the "different" coils are probably never coupled perfectly. For the losses in the magnetic material, I don't have a model (in my software), otherwise introduce an inductance model with hysteresis. In the past, I was using EM software...

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes, correct, my model (same as the one you presented in your answer), accounts for the mutual inductive coupling between turns, the values of the parameters are deduced using FEM software (GetDp). The inclusion of core losses remains a little difficult for me...

Comment: What's the ESR (winding resistance) of the inductor? What's the inductance with and without core material?

Comment: Something as this should be useful. (I used sometimes ago FLUX2D but ... ?) http://engineeringsoftwares.com/item/34/electromagnetic-simulation-software

Comment: @winny I'd have to measure that to answer you ;)

Comment: That's my point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, here is some kind of modelling ...
You can see the effect of coupling.
Sorry, no core losses taken into account in this case. Other inductor model needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Antonio for the response. I am aware of these models, however a difficulty arises when accounting for the core losses plus the not-so-purely inductive behavior before the first resonance..